# Recursion: function catch the element I want but doesn't return it

Tags: javascript, recursion, undefined

I have this simple function to catch a specific DOM element:

```
_retrieveMainContactsBox(el){
    if(el.classList.contains('contacts')){
      return el
    }
    this._retrieveMainContactsBox(el.parentElement)
  }
```

but when I call it inside  another function it returns undefined:

```
_initPhone(){
    let self = this;
    this.phoneTrigger.addEventListener('click',function(){
      if (window.matchMedia("(max-width: 893px)").matches){
        let main = self._retrieveMainContactsBox(this)
        console.log(main) // undefined
        TweenLite.to(main,.1,{width:"80%"})
      }
      TweenLite.to(self.phone,1,{autoAlpha:1,top:'0',left:'0',zIndex:20})

      $(self.phoneText).textillate('start')
    })
  }
```

Basically, the main variable result to be undefined, but if I do `console.log` inside the first function, the element I want is printed out, I don't understand why is not returning it.

Comment: _“I dont understend why is not returning it”_ - because _you_ neglected to do so! `this._retrieveMainContactsBox(el.parentElement)` - this line doesn’t return anything back to the caller.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I dont understend why is not returning it

You need to `return` the recursive call as well, otherwise unless `el`'s `classList` has that class, you are likely to get `undefined` since nothing got returned from the function.

```
_retrieveMainContactsBox(el){
    if(el.classList.contains('contacts')){
      return el
    }
    return self._retrieveMainContactsBox(el.parentElement) //observe return here
}
```